# How to write a nested loop over several arguments in a macro?

Tags: rust, macros

The following code

```
macro_rules! test {
    ( $( $x1:expr ),*; blub $( $x2:expr ),* ) => {
        $(
            println!("{} * {} = {}", $x1, $x2, $x1 * $x2);
        )*
    }
}

fn main() {
    test!{1, 2, 3; blub 4, 5, 6};
}
```

prints:

```
1 * 4 = 4
2 * 5 = 10
3 * 6 = 18
```

However I want to loop over both lists seperately like a nested loop. It should print:

```
1 * 4 = 4
1 * 5 = 5
1 * 6 = 6
2 * 4 = 8
2 * 5 = 10
2 * 6 = 12
3 * 4 = 12
3 * 5 = 15
3 * 6 = 18
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a nested loop in some form or another because you need to iterate over `x2` a variable number of times. You can expand each of your repeated tokens separately into an array, and loop over it the same way you would any iterable collection:

```rust
macro_rules! test {
    ( $($x1:expr ),*; blub $($x2:expr ),* ) => {
        for x1 in [$($x1),*] {
            for x2 in [$($x2),*] {
                println!("{} * {} = {}", x1, x2, x1 * x2);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    test!{1, 2, 3; blub 4, 5, 6};
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way I found was to cheat a little by using a token tree as one of the arguments like this:

```rust
macro_rules! test {
    // secondary invocation with a `[]` delimited list of parameters
    // as the first arguments and a single second argument.
    ( [ $( $x1:expr),* ] ; $x2:expr ) => {
        $(
            println!("{:?} * {:?} = {:?}", $x1, $x2, $x1 * $x2);
        )*
    };

    // the main invocation of the macro, takes a token tree `x1`
    // and a `[]` delimited `,` separated list of arguments for
    // each of which it calls itself again with `x1` as first
    // parameter and the element of the list as the second
    ( $x1:tt [ $( $x2:expr ),* ] ) => {
        $(
            test!($x1; $x2);
        )*
    };
}

fn main() {
    test!{
        [1, 2, 3]
        [4, 5, 6]
    };
}
```